# What is the power factor of a classical power supply?

Tags: power-supply, reactive-power, real-power

What is the power factor of a classical power supply ? I mean a transformer, rectifier and filter capacitor. Is it constant ?

Comment: This depends on the size of the decoupling capacitor and that one depends on the amount of ripple which is acceptable.

Comment: I measured a PF for a classical PSU and when loaded I read PF around 0.4...0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one answer.  No, it is not constant.

Think about it.  When there is no load on the output, the transformer primary just looks like a inductor.  However, when there is a load there are current spike twice per line cycle when the rectifiers conduct.  That adds a lot of harmonics, which contribute to a lower power factor.

Answer (score 1):

When a bridge rectifier is used you get a very non-linear current taken from the AC supply because the diodes are only conducting for a small duration of the time: -

[image]

This can make the overall power factor very poor but it is load dependent and this means there is no one fixed value for power factor.